# install doorkeeper provider and client with different RackSubUri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, oauth-2.0

I install

```
git://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper-provider-app.git
```

and

```
git://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper-devise-client.git
```

with

```
RackBaseURI /provider
```

and

```
RackBaseURI /client
```

respectively, using apache2 and passenger.

Now some OAuth redirections do not work any more.

The provider should redirect to
https://example.org/provider/users/sign_in
but goes to
https://example.org/users/sign_in

I think I have dealt with the client's redirection correctly in the client by
editing config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :doorkeeper, DOORKEEPER_APP_ID, DOORKEEPER_APP_SECRET,         :client_options => {
:site => DOORKEEPER_APP_URL,
:authorize_url => "#{DOORKEEPER_APP_URL}/provider/oauth/authorize",
:ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs"}
}
```

But as shown above I cannot find what to do in the provider.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Oauth or Doorkeeper seem not to be aware of the 
RackBaseURI /provider

So I try to adapt the routes

```
devise_for :users, path: "provider/users"
```

works for generating paths. It creates:

```
new_user_session GET    /provider/users/sign_in(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
user_session POST   /provider/users/sign_in(.:format)        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

However I have a new problem in that incoming urls are no more recognized!
So give an additional path to the same actions:

```
devise_scope :user do
get  "/users/sign_in" , to:  "devise/sessions#new"
post "/users/sign_in" , to: "devise/sessions#create"
end
```

I have pieced this together, did not come across documentation telling that this is the way to do it.